# Insert NA values in Mysql table RMySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, r, rmysql, r-dbi

I am trying to insert a data frame row in a mysql table, but I have NA values in character and numeric columns. I'm getting this error: Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
could not run statement: Unknown column 'NA' in 'field list'

This is my query:

```
sql <- sprintf("insert into payment (amount,payment_type,date,customer_total,base_price, p2c_total, partner_total, pay_online, pay_at_lot,tax,first_name_on_card,last_name_on_card,address)
                  values (%f, %d, '%s',%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,%f,'%s','%s','%s');",
                 payments[i,]$amount,payments[i,]$payment_type,payments[i,]$date, payments[i,]$customer_total,
                 payments[i,]$base_price, payments[i,]$p2c_total, payments[i,]$partner_total,
                 payments[i,]$pay_online,payments[i,]$pay_at_lot,payments[i,]$tax,
                 payments[i,]$first_name_on_card, payments[i,]$last_name_on_card, payments[i,]$address)
rs <- dbSendQuery(db, sql[i])
dbClearResult(rs)
```

This is the sql code:

```
insert into reservation (reservation_number, driver_name, number_passengers, checkin_datetime, checkout_datetime, days, reservation_date, reservation_email,id_reservation_status, id_payment, id_ship, id_facility, id_user) values ('j990j','CB', 4, '2020-01-12 10:00:00', '2020-01-19 10:30:00', 8, 'NA', 'cb@gmail.com',NA, 1, 2, 547, 6);
```

And this is the mysql error:
#1054 - La columna 'NA' en field list es desconocida

MySQL version: 8.0.27

R version: 4.03

RMySQL package: 0.10.22

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `DBI::dbAppendTable`? Since it appears `payments` is already a frame, you can subset your frame (if needed) and either insert one row or all of them at once. The use of `sprintf` to formulate a query in order to insert data in a SQL-friendly shape seems unnecessary.

Comment: But if you really want to bypass the convenience and safeguards that `dbAppendTable` provides, then you need to condition on the value, where if it is `NA` then the value in your query should be `null`, otherwise `'%f'`. Yes, this means you need to include single-quotes only if the value being inserted is not `NA`.

Comment: I use dbSendQuery for each row of payment dataset because I need the inserted id to insert in another table. id_payment is autonumeric in payment and a foreign key in another table named reservation. If I use dbAppenTable, how i get the id of each payment?

Comment: Okay, yes, that always throws a wrench into it. Ugh, I recall that issue, one reason I dislike auto-increment IDs. Unfortunately, I think MySQL makes this hard with no safe way around it. In that case, see the 2nd option in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways to look at this:

1. Don't `sprintf`/`paste` *data* into a query string. In addition to security concerns about *malicious* [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (e.g., XKCD's [*Exploits of a Mom*](https://xkcd.com/327/) aka "Little Bobby Tables"), it is also a concern for malformed strings or Unicode-vs-ANSI mistakes, even if it's one data analyst running the query.

   Conveniently, there's a function that takes care of inserting data from a `data.frame` into the table in a safer way: `dbAppendTable`. You might be able to do just

   ```r
   dbAppendTable(db, "payment", payments[i,])
   ```

   if all of the columns need to be inserted, otherwise something more verbose is necessary:

   ```r
   dbAppendTable(db, "payment", payments[i,c("amount", "payment_type", "date", "customer_total", "base_price", "p2c_total", "partner_total", "pay_online", "pay_at_lot", "tax", "first_name_on_card", "last_name_on_card", "address")])
   ```

   If you're planning on doing this for more than 1 row, then `dbAppendTable` can take multiple rows with no issue.
2. If you really want to do one row at a time with your own `insert` statement, then I strongly urge you to use parameterized queries, perhaps something like:

   ```r
   qry <- "insert into payment (amount,payment_type,date,customer_total,base_price, p2c_total, partner_total, pay_online, pay_at_lot,tax,first_name_on_card,last_name_on_card,address)
                     values (?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
   dbExecute(db, qry, params = payments[i, c("amount", "payment_type", ...)])
   ```

   (That reminds me ... `dbExecute` is a nice wrapper that does `dbSendStatement` always followed by `dbClearResult`. There's also `dbGetQuery` which is really `dbSendQuery` always followed by `dbClearResult`, returning the data. You aren't returning rows from the table, so the first is preferred anyway.)

   **NOTE**: this feature requires an up-to-date driver for accessing the database. If you're using `RMySQL` then there is a problem: that package has not seen substantive updates in years (as of now) and does not support parameterized queries. I believe the [`RMariaDB`](https://github.com/r-dbi/RMariaDB) package is both fully compatible with MySQL *and* it supports parameterized queries.
3. If you must really do this manually (and really, I discourage it strongly, too many times I thought I could work around the risks, only to be bitten each time), then R's `NA` translates into `null` (no quotes!). To do this, you need to conditionally add quotes. Something like:

   ```r
   ifelse(is.na(payments[i,]$date), "null", sQuote(payments[i,]$date))
   ```

   for *each* string-like field in your query, and make sure to change `'%s'` to `%s` in your format. There are almost certainly better ways to automate this so that you aren't typing a dozen or more `ifelse`s, but in my opinion it really is not worth the pain of doing that.

   (If you're relying on different semantics of `sprintf("%s", ..)` versus the implicit string-ification with `sQuote`, then you may need even more elbow-grease there.)

Comment: I use dbSendQuery for each row of payment dataset because I need the inserted id to insert in another table. id_payment is autonumeric in payment and a foreign key in another table named reservation. With dbAppendTable I got an error in the field list, but I was able to do it using dbWriteTable with append, and row.names params in FALSE. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

wrap your `NA` to `'NA'`

```
insert into reservation (reservation_number, driver_name, number_passengers, checkin_datetime, checkout_datetime, days, reservation_date, reservation_email,id_reservation_status, id_payment, id_ship, id_facility, id_user) values ('j990j','CB', 4, '2020-01-12 10:00:00', '2020-01-19 10:30:00', 8, 'NA', 'cb@gmail.com','NA', 1, 2, 547, 6);
```